# (Done) Is this viable for reopening?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

Is this ok to reopen given the edits I made?

[How do I represent a lengthy career marred by a recent short stint at a role I was let go from in my CV?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/37248/8146)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It had 3 reopen votes - I just cast the fourth (and binding).

Great edit!